# GAS TypeError: SpreadsheetApp.getUI is not a functionDetails

Tags: function, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to learn some basic google scripting.

I tried reading through this several times, thought about it overnight and searched all over SO and a google for answers and feel like I'm missing something stupid.

When I click the menu item I've added to my gsheet to kick of the sidepage I get this error:

> TypeError: SpreadsheetApp.getUI is not a function  Details(/link)

If I click that details link I get the same message in a message box:

> TypeError: SpreadsheetApp.getUI is not a function

Here's my code:

```
//@OnlyCurrentDoc

function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp
  .getUi()
  .createMenu("Admin")
  .addItem("Admin page", "showAdminSidebar")
  .addToUi();
}

function showAdminSidebar(){
  var widget = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("<h1>Sidebar<h1>");
  SpreadsheetApp.getUI().showSidebar(widget);
}
```

I know I must be missing something simple, so thanks for any advice you can give me.

Comment: `UI` !== ```Ui```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by @TheMaster  above, there is a typo on the method `showAdminSidebar()`.
`...SpreadsheetApp.getUI().showSidebar(widget);...` where getUI() should be getUi().

See [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getui) of methods the class SpreadsheetApp has.

Just tested here and it works just fine after fixing it.